# Correcting htaccess for friendly seo urls

Tags: .htaccess

hello i have a url like these

```
/index.php?a=page&b=privacy
/index.php?a=profile&b=username
/index.php?a=home
```

im looking for a way to make these into

```
/page/privacy
/profile/username
/home
```

currently im using this rule on my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?a=$1&q=$3 [L]
```

but this only works for /home but not on others.
im no brainer when it comes to htaccess and would appreciate a little hand. i tried searching throughout stackoverflow but they have different settings than i do so i cant find any useful ones.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change the Rules to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?a=$1 [L]
```

Comment: ok it seems to work but, it seems its only working for users that are logged in.

i mean, if i visit /profile/username
it shows up fine. but using different username, it goes back to the user originally, logged in. if the user is logged out though, you cannot even access the url /profile/username.

is it because of getting rid of?
    RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f

hmm..

Comment: Did you check the final URLs directly? Does `/index.php?a=profile&b=username` work for you when logged out?

Comment: i finally got it ALL working using these, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321348/ajax-slow-loading-after-htaccess-implementation but there is a slight problem, my website seems to load slowers than before, it might be because of redirection, mind checking out my new post?